# How to make akka-http logRequest log to a specific logger log file

Tags: scala, akka, logback, slf4j, akka-http

I have a Main non-actor class where routes are defined.

I would like to log the incoming requests to those routes into a specific log file but they are being logged into the "root" log file.

```
val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("access_log")l
logger.info("log to access log") //<--- is logged in access log file

val routes =
      path("ping" ) {
          logRequest("logging ping", Logging.InfoLevel) { <-- logged to root log
            complete("pong")
          }
        }
      }
```

The [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/debugging-directives/logRequest.html) states that "To change the logger, wrap this directive by withLog.", but I don't know how to change my `logger` into a `LoggingAdapter` that `withLog` is called with.

My logback.xml has a logger entry

```
 <logger name="access_log" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ACCESSLOG" />
    </logger>
```

Can anyone help?

Edit 2: following @Ramon J Romero y Vigil's update to his answer I realise I can simply (given a correctly configured logback.xml) do:

```
val accessLog = Logging(system.eventStream, "access_log")

val routes =
  path("ping" ) {
    withLog(accessLog) {
      logRequest("ping", Logging.InfoLevel) {
        complete("pong")
      }
    }
  }
```

Edit:

Based on @Ramon J Romero y Vigil's answer I was able to get the requests logged to my access_log by doing the following:

```
val loggingAdapter : LoggingAdapter = new LoggingAdapter {
      override def isDebugEnabled : Boolean = logger.isDebugEnabled
      override def isErrorEnabled : Boolean = logger.isErrorEnabled
      override def isInfoEnabled : Boolean = logger.isInfoEnabled
      override def isWarningEnabled : Boolean = logger.isWarnEnabled

      override def notifyDebug(message: String): Unit = logger.debug(message)

      override protected def notifyError(message: String): Unit =  logger.error(message)

      override protected def notifyError(cause: Throwable, message: String): Unit = logger.error(message, cause)

      override protected def notifyWarning(message: String): Unit = logger.warn(message)

      override protected def notifyInfo(message: String): Unit = logger.info(message)
    }

    val routes =
      path("ping" ) {
        withLog(loggingAdapter) {
          logRequest("**ping**", Logging.InfoLevel) {
            complete("pong")
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you have to use `LoggerFactory`**

It appears as if you are using `slf4j` directly instead of using akka's logging mechanisms, but you want akka to use the slf4j `Logger` instead of its own [`LoggingAdapter`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.19/akka/event/LoggingAdapter.html).  This type of mixing & matching of log systems isn't advised, it is easier to stick with one or the other.

If this mixing is necessary then you can just create a LoggingAdapter manually by using the `Logger` that you've already created and overriding all of the abstract fields in LoggingAdapter:

```
val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("access_log")

val loggingAdapter : LoggingAdapter = new LoggingAdapter {
  override def isDebugEnabled : Boolean = logger.isDebugEnabled
  override def isErrorEnabled : Boolean = logger.isErrorEnabled
  ...
}
```

The adapter can now be used by adding the [`withLog`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/basic-directives/withLog.html) directive.

**Using Akka Logging Directly**

It is much easier to utilize [akka's logging functionality](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/logging.html#logging) directly.

This still allows you to [interact with the slf4j api](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/logging.html#slf4j).  By using the slf4j API you can specify which logback appender you want to use, including [file appenders](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender) in which the output file is specified in configuration settings.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion works for me. I am wondering about the fact that "mixing & matching of log systems isn't advised". How should I log "logRequest" logs to a file of my choosing (e.g "access_log") using Akka's LoggingAdapter?

Comment: @user5325596 You are welcome.  I have updated my answer to reflect how to use akka logging directly and specify an output file.  Happy hacking.

Comment: Thanks again. Your update helped me get to the "right" way of doing it.