# How to configure logback to get nice logs of akka-http logRequest event

Tags: scala, akka, logback, slf4j, akka-http

As a result of the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54480020/how-to-make-akka-http-logrequest-log-to-a-specific-logger-log-file) I am able to get logRequest to log to a file called access.log.

I have

```
val routes =
      path("ping" ) {
        withLog(accessLog) {
          logRequest("ping", Logging.InfoLevel) {
            complete("pong")
          }
        }
      }
```

Part of my logback.xml configuration looks like

```
 <appender name="ACCESSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>log/access.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>log/access-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>64 MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
```

And the resulting entry in the log file looks like

```
2019-02-06 16:51:04 ping: HttpRequest(HttpMethod(GET),http://localhost:8080/ping,List(Host: localhost:8080, Connection: keep-alive, Cache-Control: max-age=0, Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1, User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36, Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, image/webp, image/apng, */*;q=0.8, Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, Accept-Language: en-GB, en-US;q=0.9, en;q=0.8, Cookie: xxx, Timeout-Access: <function1>),HttpEntity.Strict(none/none,ByteString()),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
```

What can I do to get my log entries to look something like

```
2019-02-06 16:51:04 GET /ping <time_taken>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a method that will produce a `LogEntry` and you set your log message in the way you want.

```
  def myLogEntry(req: HttpRequest): LogEntry = {
    LogEntry(s"${req.method} /${req.uri.path}", Logging.InfoLevel)
  }

  logRequest(myLogEntry _) {
    complete("pong")
  }
```

The problem is with information like `<time_taken>` as it's not available when directive `logRequest` is executed. This directive prints log message on incoming http request when directive is triggered. There is no information yet for the inner route result, completed or rejected.

Check out this [blog post](https://blog.softwaremill.com/measuring-response-time-in-akka-http-7b6312ec70cf) to see how time can be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) for the `pattern`.

We are fine with this one:

```
  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel" />
    ...
  <appender ...>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
    </encoder>
 </appender>
```

Here is another example (where I found the results):

```
<appender name="ACCESS_FILE" ...>
  ....     
    <encoder>
            <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger - %message%n%xException</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

This gives you:

```
2018-06-26 12:13:50,377 [INFO] from access-filter - 6. GET /assets/javascripts/versioned.js took 113ms and returned 200
2018-06-26 12:13:50,377 [INFO] from access-filter - 6. GET /assets/scala-adapters-client-jsdeps.js took 113ms and returned 200
```

Comment: When I do as you suggest I get  `%PARSER_ERROR[coloredLevel] ` and I still end up with the full log entry as described in my question.

Comment: sorry, for the coloredLevel you need one more config - see my updated answer

Comment: That would only work if I was using the play framework right? And it still would leave the message part as  `HttpRequest(HttpMethod(GET),http://localhost:8080/ping,List(` etc

Comment: yes I use play framework - I added another example where I found the result - BUT just check the docu - you can do a LOT;)